# Deleting file in tar mounted with archivemount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, tar, fuse

[archivemount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivemount) allows rw-mounting tar archives.

*What happens when I delete a file? Is it actually removed from the tar archive? Is a delete flag set?*

If the file is actually removed, then I assume the operation to be painfully slow, because the whole archive would need to be rewritten, at least from the point where the file has been deleted.

Comment: I'm surprised by the down votes. It this not a valid question?

Comment: Questions typically get downvoted due to topicality or level of details. Usually there is an expectation of 'show your own working', which you're lacking here.

Comment: @Sobrique I like to keep questions terse, only adding detail where I believe it helps with understanding the question. If you think this question could be improved, then please let me know how.

Comment: I'd suggest here: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask - that's probably the baseline that's being referred to when you're getting downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test this fairly easily

create a tar file

```
tar -cf test.tar this.txt that.txt
```

Get it's inode number for later comparison

```
ls -i test.tar
24903987 test.tar
```

Mount the test.tar archive and delete a file from it

```
archivemount test.tar /mnt/a
rm /mnt/a/that.txt
ls -i test.tar
24903987 test.tar
```

Note above that the file retains it's original inode number. Lets unmount the tar file and see wnat happens

```
umount /mnt/a
ls -i test.tar
24903988 test.tar
```

The inode number has changed so it's a new file. This would likely be very slow on a large archive.

Comment: Thanks for the test! I thought I ask before I go through the potential hassle of installing `archivemount`.

Comment: I installed it and ran the tests in less than 5 minutes - it's trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand archivemount correctly, it does not actually update the contents of the archive file before you unmount it. When unmounting, it re-creates the archive and sure, with a huge archive file this will be slow.